# In App Purchase - Help on Last stage - downloading content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have implemented IAP into my app however I am having a problem figuring out where the user is supposed to find the purchased content after they pay.

Using my test account, when I click the buy button, it marks the IAP with a tick as if to show that its bought but then from there I can't find the content...

**Can someone assist me as to what I need to add to my code and storyboard so the user is able to access their purchased content.... (The content will be several short videos available to the user through IAP)**

From what I have read through all the tutorials, I think the code im missing is this:

```
-(void)paymentQueueSKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloadsNSArray *)downloads
{
    for (SKDownload *download in downloads)
    {
        switch (download.downloadState) {
            case SKDownloadStateActive:
                NSLog(@"Download progress = %f", 
                download.progress);
                NSLog(@"Download time = %f", 
                download.timeRemaining);
            break;
            case SKDownloadStateFinished:
                // Download is complete. Content file URL is at 
                // path referenced by download.contentURL. Move 
                // it somewhere safe, unpack it and give the user 
                // access to it
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**However I also need a method to transfer the completed downloads back into the app and then link a view controller to those downloads/purchased content (How do I do this?)**

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? In addition to this method, of course, you need to set your class as an observer, or that method never gets called. I've had a download actually come down from a test server only once so far (still haven't found out if the problem is Apple servers or my code). What I did get was a zip file, which I opened as a directory. I could then read the contents as if they were regular files and write them elsewhere as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code from one of my apps which will hopefully help you. Essentially what you have to do is determine the index of the product that was purchased and then provide content based on that. If you only have one in-app purchase then you can simply provide the content after the purchase notification.

```
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [self makeSuccessAlert];

    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
            if (idx == 0) {
                coins = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[coins integerValue] + 5000];
                NSLog(@"coins %d", [coins integerValue]);
                [totalCoins setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins.integerValue]];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:coins forKey:@"coins"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            }
            if (idx == 1) {
                coins = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[coins integerValue] + 15000];
                NSLog(@"coins %d", [coins integerValue]);
                [totalCoins setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins.integerValue]];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:coins forKey:@"coins"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }

            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: i already have this method, and my IAP is non-consumable yours is coins so a consumable. however this on its own wouldnt fix this issue as i need to be able to "download the items" then get them from the directory downloaded to then back into the app and allow the user to view their content purchased.